# In two circles, A and B are the centers of unit circles intersecting each other Find the area of the region common to both the circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

In the figure, $A$ and $B$ are the centres of unit circles intersecting each other. Find the area of the region common to both the circles.

[image: Circles that intersect each other]

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where is this question from? I am voting to close this question due to lack of [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/545914).

Comment: Hint: try constructing triangles between points $A$ and $B$ and the points at which the circles intersect.

Comment: You have to add two circle segments, depending on the angle and distance from the centres.

Comment: Hint: Think about how you construct equilateral triangles. That should give you the relevant angle to use.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Connect the intersection points, find the area outside the triangle but inside the sector in one of the circles, then multiply by a factor of 2